# Flautist versus Flutist - which is correct?

Tags: usage

I've always come across "flautist" as the correct word (to denote a person who plays the flute). However, flutist also seems to be an accepted form in some writings. Which one is the correct or rather more accepted form? Or is it different in different geographies?

Comment: I think it's similar to *colour* and *color*.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but *flutist* is more common in American English, while *flautist* is more common in British English.

Comment: And ***flautist*** reads and sounds more authoritative.